# Syllabify geology

Tags: syntactic-analysis

How do we syllabify the word "geology?  Ge ol o gy or ge o lo gy. If A is right then why is B  wrong? If B so then why A?

Also 2. laboratory.

Comment: Dictionaries usually show this.

Comment: This means both  parts...

Comment: _Laboratory_ is pronounced differently in American and British English.

Answer (score 1):

According to the rules [of open and closed syllables](https://www.spelfabet.com.au/2014/05/open-and-closed-syllables/), the vowel of a syllable should be a *long vowel* if the syllable does not end with a consonant sound.

For example:

"me" has a long vowel; "met" has a short vowel

"go" has a long vowel; "got" has a short vowel

"hi" has a long vowel; "hit" has a short vowel

These are arbitrary rules invented by English teachers, and there are lots of exceptions, but let's try applying them to your case.

In "geology", the first O is a short vowel, while the second O is a schwa (neutral) vowel. Well, the rules above don't say anything about schwa vowels. But at least we can make the first O into a closed syllable.

So according to the rules we discussed, it should be **ge-ol-o-gy** so the first O would be in a "closed syllable".

There doesn't seem to be any rule about what to do with schwa syllables. So I suggest you just hit your hand on a table while chanting "geology" and hear what it sounds like.

PS: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/geology) says "ge-ol-o-gy"

Comment: It's probably influenced by the prefix geo- which is used to construct a lot of English words (geomagnetism, geophysics, geodynamics, geopolitics) and occurs as an element in a lot more (geography, geodesic, geometry), giving the sense that "geo" is a separate part of the word to be pronounced separately. Likewise -logy is a common suffix or element.

Comment: @Stuart You are correct about those words' etymology. With some words formed by adding a prefix to a root word, I agree. However, if there's no root which is also used on its own as a word, which syllable bears the stress is determined more by the nature of the last few syllables, and is often on the last syllable but two no matter how many syllables the whole word has. How the word then divides into syllables is influenced by where the stress falls. In many cases this makes a syllable consisting of the prefix's o and the following consonant, e.g. ge-OM-e-try.